# How to insert a copy of the top row per group in Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to insert a copy(with some slight modifications) of the first record per group in a table. I can get the complete first record per group using a "with" statement and and a row number over a partition.

```
     with rankedByTime_PerInteraction as(
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION By displayId, ObjectId, InteractionId order by AssetLog.Recorded Desc) as timeRank,         
    CasLog.*


    FROM         AssetLog INNER JOIN CasLog ON AssetLog.Id = CasLog.ID 
        where   FixType > 0
    )   
select newId()
           ,EVENTCOUNT
           ,PROTOCOLVERSION
           ,EVENTLOOKUPSET
           ,2000
           ,DISPLAYSERIAL
           ,DISPLAYID
           ,MACHINETYPE
           ,GEAR
           ,RF_NODE
           ,OBJECTSERIAL
           ,OBJECTRSSILEVEL
           ,OBJECTSTATUS
           ,OBJECTID
           ,OBJECTINFO
           ,CASTIMESTAMP
           ,SPARE1
           ,SPARE2
           ,[CHECKSUM]
           ,ALARMTIME
           ,MINRANGE
           ,EventId
           ,InteractionId
from rankedByTime_PerInteraction    
where timeRank = 1
```

Which works great. However I would like to use this in a insert into statment like.

```
    INSERT INTO [CasLog]
           ([ID]
           ,[EVENTCOUNT]
           ,[PROTOCOLVERSION]
           ,[EVENTLOOKUPSET]
           ,[EVENTNUMBER]
           ,[DISPLAYSERIAL]
           ,[DISPLAYID]
           ,[MACHINETYPE]
           ,[GEAR]
           ,[RF_NODE]
           ,[OBJECTSERIAL]
           ,[OBJECTRSSILEVEL]
           ,[OBJECTSTATUS]
           ,[OBJECTID]
           ,[OBJECTINFO]
           ,[CASTIMESTAMP]
           ,[SPARE1]
           ,[SPARE2]
           ,[CHECKSUM]
           ,[ALARMTIME]
           ,[MINRANGE]
           ,[EventId]
           ,[InteractionId])

with rankedByTime_PerInteraction as(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION By displayId, ObjectId, InteractionId order by AssetLog.Recorded Desc) as timeRank,         
        CasLog.*
        FROM         AssetLog INNER JOIN CasLog ON AssetLog.Id = CasLog.ID 
        where   FixType > 0
    )   
select newId()
           ,EVENTCOUNT
           ,PROTOCOLVERSION
           ,EVENTLOOKUPSET
           ,2000
           ,DISPLAYSERIAL
           ,DISPLAYID
           ,MACHINETYPE
           ,GEAR
           ,RF_NODE
           ,OBJECTSERIAL
           ,OBJECTRSSILEVEL
           ,OBJECTSTATUS
           ,OBJECTID
           ,OBJECTINFO
           ,CASTIMESTAMP
           ,SPARE1
           ,SPARE2
           ,[CHECKSUM]
           ,ALARMTIME
           ,MINRANGE
           ,EventId
           ,InteractionId
from rankedByTime_PerInteraction    
where timeRank = 1
```

However I get an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Is it possible to do use the with statement within an insert statement?

If not how can I best insert a copy of the first record per group in a table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [CasLog]
           ([ID]
           ,[EVENTCOUNT]
           ,[PROTOCOLVERSION]
           ,[EVENTLOOKUPSET]
           ,[EVENTNUMBER]
           ,[DISPLAYSERIAL]
           ,[DISPLAYID]
           ,[MACHINETYPE]
           ,[GEAR]
           ,[RF_NODE]
           ,[OBJECTSERIAL]
           ,[OBJECTRSSILEVEL]
           ,[OBJECTSTATUS]
           ,[OBJECTID]
           ,[OBJECTINFO]
           ,[CASTIMESTAMP]
           ,[SPARE1]
           ,[SPARE2]
           ,[CHECKSUM]
           ,[ALARMTIME]
           ,[MINRANGE]
           ,[EventId]
           ,[InteractionId])

select newId()
           ,EVENTCOUNT
           ,PROTOCOLVERSION
           ,EVENTLOOKUPSET
           ,2000
           ,DISPLAYSERIAL
           ,DISPLAYID
           ,MACHINETYPE
           ,GEAR
           ,RF_NODE
           ,OBJECTSERIAL
           ,OBJECTRSSILEVEL
           ,OBJECTSTATUS
           ,OBJECTID
           ,OBJECTINFO
           ,CASTIMESTAMP
           ,SPARE1
           ,SPARE2
           ,[CHECKSUM]
           ,ALARMTIME
           ,MINRANGE
           ,EventId
           ,InteractionId
from (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION By displayId, ObjectId, InteractionId order by AssetLog.Recorded Desc) as timeRank,         
        CasLog.*
        FROM         AssetLog INNER JOIN CasLog ON AssetLog.Id = CasLog.ID 
        where   FixType > 0
    ) AS rankedByTime_PerInteraction
where timeRank = 1
```

if you want to get one row only you can use SELECT TOP 1 newid()...